# SVG Inject file to DOM from scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, ionic-framework

I'm working on app with SVG map. I installed module SVGInjector https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector.
It works but only with static URL like:

```
<img class="inject-me" src="data/maps/building1.svg">
```

I would like to change map based on variable from URL ($stateParams).
My controller looks like this:

```
function MapSingleCtrl(
    $scope,
    $stateParams,
    UserService,
    $ionicPopup,
    $state,
    $log
  ) {

    var vm = this;


    var mapSingle = {"id": $stateParams.id, "building": $stateParams.building, "floor": $stateParams.floor, "roomID": $stateParams.roomID, "room": $stateParams.room};

    $scope.svgMap = "data/maps/building1.svg";
    $scope.mapSingle = mapSingle;

    // Inject SVG
    var mySVGsToInject = document.querySelectorAll('img.inject-me');
    //console.log(mySVGsToInject);
    SVGInjector(mySVGsToInject);

  }
```

And then when I use:

```
<img class="inject-me" src="{{svgMap}}">
```

File load but I can only see it, not interact with it - CSS hover doesn't work anymore.

What can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance for any advice! ;)

Comment: Images are not interactive you'd need to include the SVG online or via an object or I frame tag.

Comment: I know, this module makes it SVG. "Any DOM element, or array of elements, passed to SVGInjector with an SVG file src or data-src attribute will be replaced with the full SVG markup inline"